# What is the meaning of "laughing out"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The class didn't seem to mind the plot. They loved it. They were laughing out there.

I wonder in that context what the meaning of *out* is.

Comment: It's part of the phrase _out there_.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of it wrong.

Your grouping:

> They were | laughing out | there

when it should be

> They were | laughing | out there

"out there" is a phrase meaning basically something outside or away.

Comment: thanks DaemonOfTheWest. What about the expression "laughing out loudly". is it completely different?

Comment: then I can't understand the meaning. I don't guess the sentence means the class laughing outside or laughing away. I guess "out" in that context means something like completely. I wonder if I am right. Please pardon my terrible English.

Comment: @AR AM: ***Out loud*** is by way of contrast with *silently, inwardly* (as in *"He laughed to himself"*).

Comment: @ARAM There's no context in your quote. It could be said by an actor on a stage, talking about an audience "out there".

Comment: Even if it's not said by an actor, it is still quite frequent to say, “out there in the audience”.